# What is the benefit of using HTML5 cache over good old cache control HTTP headers?

Tags: html, caching

What would I gain from creating and maintaining a manifest file while I can send vary and expires header to set the client cache for 6 months and then append a prefix to all my static media URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 Application Cache does a slightly different thing. It allows you to selectively store parts (or wholes) of an applications, to allow it to operate offline.

It's not about saving bandwidth, it's about working with offline applications.

**[Read more](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)**